# How can I sort the input string "DC501GCCCA098911" as to OutPut: "CD015ACCCG011899" using Python3?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I sort the input string "DC501GCCCA098911" as to outPut: "CD015ACCCG011899" using Python3 ?

Comment: Can you explain the logic by which you get the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information. I'm going to assume it's split on alpha/numeric boundaries:

```
from re import split

inp = "DC501GCCCA098911"

out = ''.join(''.join(sorted(list(sub))) for sub in split(r"([A-Z]+|[0-9]+)", inp) if sub)
print(out)  // Prints CD015ACCCG011899
```

In a nutshell this creates a regular expression that creates groups of strings that are all letters or numbers, then creates a list out of each group, sorts it, and joins it all back together.